# lvresize: command not found - RedHat

Tags: linux, redhat, memory, swap

No search results on google for this. So i am really confused now.

I am trying to increase the swap space and lvresize says command not found. Please Help !!

using RedHat 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the package `lvm2` installed (check with `rpm -qa|grep lvm2`) and `/usr/sbin` in your $PATH.
Or call it via `/usr/sbin/lvresize` directly.